# Vim Ale linter plugin not working for python code in Windows 10

Tags: python, vim, windows-10, vim-plugin, flake8

I have latest GVim (v8.2) 64-bit and Miniconda Python 3.8.5 64-bit installed on Windows 10. I am working in the virtual environment `da38` and included the following two lines in my `$HOME\_vimrc` file to point to the correct python interpreter and libraries for this environment:

```
set pythonthreehome=$HOME\miniconda3\envs\da38
set pythonthreedll=$HOME\miniconda3\envs\da38\python38.dll
```

Both `:echo has('python3')` and `:echo has('python3_dynamic')` return 1. I have installed Vim plugin [dense-analysis/ale](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) for python linting, and installed `flake8` and `black` packages in `da38` using `conda install flake8 black`. And I added the following lines in `$HOME\_vimrc` to configure this plugin:

```
let g:ale_linters = {'python': ['flake8']}
let g:ale_fixers = {'*': [], 'python': ['black']}
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 1
```

But the plugin does not show any error on a python file that has many by design: running `flake8 test.py` on command prompt returns a lot of errors. `:ALEInfo` repeats these two lines several times:

```
(executable check - failure) flake8
(finished - exit code 1) 'cmd /s/c "cd /d "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop" && black - < C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\VIBA694.tmp\test.py"'
```

I am wondering if somehow the correct python path is not being passed to Vim, but cannot figure out what else to do. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

### UPDATE:

I think I narrowed down the problem. Linter plugin fails when I open `test.py` with vim from the desktop icon, but works if I first activate the virtual environment with `conda activate da38` and then start vim on command prompt. I guess the desktop vim does not see the virtual environment, where the two packages `flake8` and `black` are installed. So I believe the problem is how to add the appropriate python environment to the desktop vim. I should add the [vim-conda plugin](https://github.com/cjrh/vim-conda) did not help.

### UPDATE #2:

I managed to get [vim-conda plugin](https://github.com/cjrh/vim-conda) working with gvim, and now the linter plugin works as expected.

### UPDATE #3:

One can avoid using a plugin and instead hard-code the environment path in `_vimrc` (for windows):

```
let venv = 'da38'
let mypath = 'C:\Users\Admin\miniconda3\envs\' . venv . ';'
    \      . 'C:\Users\Admin\miniconda3\envs\' . venv . '\Scripts;'
    \      . 'C:\Users\Admin\miniconda3\envs\' . venv . '\Library\bin;'
let $PATH = mypath . $PATH
```

This code sticks the env path in front of default `$PATH`.